# problems with memcpy of strings

Tags: string, memcpy

I am trying to

- take two strings (message1, message2),
- assign str1 to message1 if message1 and message2 are empty,
- assign str2 to message2 if it is empty and message1 is full,
- and save message 2 over message 1 and put message2 == message3 if both message1 and message2 were full.

I get weird results as shown. But memcpy is not working.  (I know it's my fault somehow.)

#### input

```
message1: ffW
message 2: a
message 3 (2 writes over 1, 3 writes over 2): bbb

MESSAGE 1a: ffW 
MESSAGE 2a: a_W 
MESSAGE 1ab: a_W 
MESSAGE 2ab: a_W 
MESSAGE 1b: a_W 
MESSAGE 2b: bbb
```

#### next one:

```
INPUT:
message1: a
message2: abcde
message3: abcdefg

MESSAGE 1a: a�� 
MESSAGE 2a: abcde 
MESSAGE 1ab: abcd 
MESSAGE 2ab: abcde 
MESSAGE 1b: abcd 
MESSAGE 2b: abcdefg
```

.

```
    if (message1[0] == '\0')
    {
        memcpy(message1, echoBuffer, sizeof echoBuffer);
        fprintf(stderr, "MESSAGE 1: %s \n", message1);
    }
    else if (message1[0] != '\0' && message2[0] == '\0')
    {
        memcpy(message2, echoBuffer, sizeof echoBuffer);
        fprintf(stderr, "MESSAGE 2: %s \n", message2);
    }
    else if (message1[0] != '\0' && message2[0] != '\0')
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "MESSAGE 1a: %s \n", message1);
        fprintf(stderr, "MESSAGE 2a: %s \n", message2);
        memcpy(message1, message2, sizeof message2);
        fprintf(stderr, "MESSAGE 1ab: %s \n", message1);
        fprintf(stderr, "MESSAGE 2ab: %s \n", message2);
        memcpy(message2, echoBuffer, sizeof echoBuffer);
        fprintf(stderr, "MESSAGE 1b: %s \n", message1);
        fprintf(stderr, "MESSAGE 2b: %s \n", message2);
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what is wrong?  This problem has been plaguing me.

I think the messages and echoBuffer are all 100 characters in size.

Comment: To be on the safe side, it might be worth memsetting to '\0' prior to memcpy.. memset(message1,'\0', sizeof echoBuffer);

Comment: You think, therefore they are? Have you tried running this under a debugger? That will reveal your bug.

Comment: @Brian Colvin -- how do you suppose that makes anything "safe?"

Comment: @user963070: a little care for your question (formatting, wording) goes a loooooooong way

Comment: @PeteWilson Would you disagree that its better knowing whats in the chunk of memory you're using prior to using it? If used properly memset is helpful before memcpy but yes if used incorrectly you could null out other things.  Assuming he's using it in parallel with memcpy of the same length it won't do any damage the memcpy wont already have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a particular reason for using memcpy? I believe that strcpy(char* dest, char* source) would be easier to use. Maybe it could fix your problem

You must include string.h in order to use it

Comment: One may argue that using `memcpy` can have better performance than `strcpy`, though it has to be used responsibly. Also, I for one would prefer using `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` to be safe from buffer overflow attacks.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I found it easier to read and to use when performance and security are not an issue. Nevertheless the main purpose was to find the bug, which I believe was related to the amount of copied memory. Apart from that you are absolutely right on both things

Comment: I second using `str(n)cpy` when it makes sense (semantically). Though I believe `strcpy` should really be used when you're 100% sure of the stuff you copy.

Answer (score 1):

You sure about sizeof? As I remember sizeof show size of datatype not real length of char arrays/strings.

Comment: It returns the size of the data structure. In the case of statically sized arrays of char, it'd be equivalent to the maximum length of it (that is, including terminating `\0`). In the vast majority of cases however, it would end up being a pointer size (so 32 to 64 bits in most current setups).